# Verifying grammar in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I read this article online, which contained the following phrase

> Work will continue being done to better understand the relationship between x and y.

This sounds very wrong to me, but I can't quite put my finger on it. To my mind, I would correct this to :

> Work will continue to better understand...

or

> Work will continue to be done to better understand...

Is the original phrase correct?

Comment: It's klunky enough, that's for sure.

Comment: It's an example of the sort of sentence people write in academic papers at the end, right before the "more funding is needed" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb phrase "will continue being done" is weak for at least three reaons:

- "To do" is a pretty weak verb (i.e., it contains little semantic content).
- "To be" is probably the weakest verb in English, especially in its present particple form ("being"). I sometimes tell my students to avoid "being" whenever possible (certainly not absolutely, but as a general rule of thumb).
- Both of those verbs are, in fact, redundant here. The sentence could have begun: "Work will continue to better understand . . ." (as you suggest).

Furthermore, the infinitive phrase "to understand" (which appears here as a split infinitive) lacks an explicit agent. (Who will understand?)

None of these issues is fatal by itself, but put them all together, and, yeah, this sentence probably sounds pretty yucky to most native English speakers.

Comment: This varies by region. In the South, these are not weak verbs, and they contain a lot of grammatical aspect marking that is lost on many other dialects. *Work will continue to the bridge* is very unclear, and work [will continue to be done/will continue being done] would be a mandatory distinction in many parts of the South. It distinguishes intermittent or episodic work from a drawn-out or protracted event.

Comment: "Work will continue being done in the evenings", not "work will continue to be done in the evenings." "Work will continue to be done while the courts hear the case against the contractor", not "work will continue being done while the courts hear the case against the contractor.

Comment: @PhilSweet I'm certainly not saying that "to do" should be avoided at all costs; I'm saying that well-regarded authors, writing instructors, etc. often prefer verbs with more semantic content over "to do". Compare "I did a picture" to "I painted a picture" or even "I did some work" to "I performed some work". (This is a matter of style, not grammar.) I'm not aware of any regional variation on this issue, but if there is some, then I stand corrected.